# Session Locking After Update to PHP 7

Tags: php, apache, session, nginx, php-7

Im facing with really weird problems with my PHP Framework after updated to PHP 7.
I think problem is Sessions.
Here is the problem i faced: When i send first request to my site its responding in 80ms. 1 second later, I'm calling same page again, it takes around 3-4 seconds to respond, one more request after 1 second, its takes around 10 seconds to respond. But if i wait 20-30 seconds and re-call the page, its responding in 80ms again.
So i did some debugging and i realize that when i use `session_write_close` function, its always takes 80ms to responding and working really fast. So without `session_write_close`, My session was locking and even the scripts ends i have to wait 20-30 seconds to call it again to get fast respond. Continuously refreshing page happens to respond time going higher and higher because of sessions.

So Why its happening ? First time im faced such a problem. Im writing only 100kb data to my session.

First i though that its because my hdd had some problems, so i change my session path to ram disc. But no any changes on responding time.

I completely deleted Apache and install fresh nginx server. Good thing With nginx, its not take 10 seconds to respond on my second request, but still its waiting 1-2 seconds to respond, but still its not fast as when i used  `session_write_close`. When i used `session_write_close` on nginx its working perfect too.

Also tried to delete apache 2.2 and install apache 2.4. But no chance.

By the way its happened to me on my prod server. It has Apache 2.2(also tried with 2.4) and PHP 7.0.4 and really powerfull CPU and 128GB ram with default config files and mod_rewrite enabled.
 Opcache and memcache also enabled. (I also tried disable and re-enable cache one by one, but no any change)

Funny think its working super-fast on my test server which is 10 years old with 8GB ram. It has PHP 5.4.

Edit: Im using `ob_start()` and  `ob_get_clean()` functions on my framework.

```
ob_start()
.....
.....
all requests, framework calls etc.
.....
.....
 ob_get_clean();
.....
show the page to user.
```

Edit 2: **Co-founder of Zend and Co-Architect of PHP's Zeev Suraski replied my question as "No idea off hand" on [twitter](https://twitter.com/zeevs/status/714554391500623872) . So i could kill myself :)**

Edit 3: I think its about `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()`, when i removed them its coming fast always.
Regards

Edit 4: I downgrade My prod server to Php 5.6 . Now Its working fine. I dont know why but there is a relationship between `Ob_` functions and Session handling on PHP 7. And it makes my framework slow. How do I know that ? When i used `session_write_close()` right before `ob_start()` its going really fast. Instead of using `session_write_close()` if i remove `ob_` functions, its also working fast.

Comment: have you some long running process where you open a session? (i.e, a `session_start(); while(true) { // do something }`)

Comment: Nope. Its my main page, only have 4 sql queries with 0.0080 executing time. When i write session_write_close  to that page loading is around 0.05 seconds everytime. But without that function, it takes 0.05 seconds on first request as i expected, but then 6 seconds on second request after 1 second later my first request.

Comment: The session handler has a locking mechanism that will prevent concurrent requests; can you provide some code?

Comment: I know that but PHP 56 has same locking mechanism too, which is worknig perfectly with my code in my test server. And its not making any sense to locking session to 10+ seconds for each request.

Comment: The only way to find out what's happening is to start php using valgrind, run the request and check what happened. However, that's *probably* not an option because it's a really screwed up process to find out what went wrong. This is what bothers me - you're talking about session mechanisms for writing - did you write a custom session handler? Where are you saving the contents? Database, flat files? Why on earth do you have 100 kb of data in a session? Which browser do you use? This sounds like a screwed up case of HTTP pipelining.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your answers.  I downgrade My prod server to Php 5.6 . Now Its working fine. I dont know why but there is a relationship between Ob_ functions and Session handling on PHP 7. And it makes my framework slow. How do I know that ? When i used session_write_close() right before ob_start() its going really fast. Instead of using session_write_close() if i remove ob_ functions, its also working fast.